# Why isn't the URL the same for echo and for response in WordPress Remote

Tags: wordpress

I've got this little shortcode

```
function starlight_count() {
$url = 'https://herokuapp.com/creditcount?contact_id=' . do_shortcode('[i4w_db__FirebaseID]');
$response = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( $url ) );
$api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
$response_message = wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $response );

ob_start(); ?>
<?php 
    echo $url;
echo $response_message;
    print_r($response); ?>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();

}
add_shortcode( 'starlight-count', 'starlight_count' );
```

The first echo returns

```
https://herokuapp.com/creditcount?contact_id=-KhwKGq4EYNf0GCiw8Kn
```

But the actual call returns a 500 error, and is trying to request data from

```
[url] => https://herokuapp.com/creditcount?contact_id=%5Bi4w_db__FirebaseID%5D
```

Why isn't it using the merged data URL?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling shortcode inside shortcode.

You need to do the logic like the following :

```
function starlight_count($atts) {
$params = shortcode_atts(array(
        'pass' => '0',
    ), $atts );

$url = 'https://herokuapp.com/creditcount?contact_id='.$params['pass'];
$response = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( $url ) );
$api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
$response_message = wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $response );

ob_start(); ?>
<?php
    echo $url;
//echo $response_message;
   // print_r($response); ?>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();

}
add_shortcode( 'starlight-count', 'starlight_count' );
$variable = do_shortcode('[i4w_db__FirebaseID]');
echo do_shortcode('[starlight-count pass='.$variable.']');
```